# add items to list via button click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select list and need to append each selected value/text to a list on a button click.  Here is some pseudo code

```
  $("#addButton").click(function () {           

            var selectedValue = "..."
            var selectedText = "..."

            //todo append each selected value & text
            //to an unordered list 
            //on submit of form read in via querystring selected
            //values and text from the unordered list

});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {           

  var selectedVal = $('select').val();

  $('ul').append('<li>'+selectedVal+'</li>')

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMTxE/)

Comment: It appears the text of the selected option is also needed. In that case: `$("#mySelectList option:selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However how would I read in via querystring each value and text in the unordered list?   I guess I would need to loop through the it?

Comment: @DreamToCode to have it sent on a submitted form you have to add the values to hidden input in addition to adding it to the list.

Comment: Ok thanks Shadow Wizard.  So I guess I would have an array of hidden input fields?